# How to disable <a> styled as jquery-ui button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML element `<a>` styled with jquery-ui to appear as a button. The html is shown below:

```
<a id= "delete-user"class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all">DELETE USER</a> 
<a id= "save-user" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" style="float:right">SAVE</a>
```

I have tried setting the *disabled* attribute of the element in javascript without any success. The code I have tried is shown below.

```
$("#save-user").attr("disabled", true);   //disable save button
```

The above statement works with `<input>` perfectly but not with the `<a>`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Anchor tags do *not* have a "disabled" state, therefore you can't apply "disabled" to anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` elements don't have a disabled state. jQuery UI provides a disabled state for its buttons via its own [`disabled`option](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#option-disabled), which (as the documentation shows) you set like this:

```
$("#save-user" .button( "option", "disabled", true );
```

---

Side note: On elements that *do* have a disabled state (like `input` elements), you use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) (`prop("disabled", true)`), not `attr` (`attr("disabled", true)`), to change the state of that property. (If you use `attr`, jQuery tries to do the right thing for you anyway, but it's best to understand the difference between properties and attributes and use the correct accessors.) You *can* use attributes for it, setting is `.attr("disabled", "any-string-here")` and clearing is `.removeAttr("disabled")`. But `prop` is clearer and simpler.

Side note 2: Since your `a` element isn't a link, consider using `button` or `input` instead. They *do* have a disabled state you can set via `prop` (but if you do, you have to also tell jQuery UI to update the button appearance via [`refresh`](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-refresh)).

Answer (score 0):

Disable attribute only associates button and input filelds, the thing you want to do here is , event.preventDefault . It will work like disable, but it will depend upon your coding, if you want to show it disabled, you have to add add via jquery

Comment: There's no need. If you correctly disable it with jQuery UI, jQuery UI handles it: http://output.jsbin.com/momebup

Answer (score 0):

`a` doesn't have disabled attribute. But you can do make it disabled using CSS.

```
.disabled {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
        opacity: 0.6;
}

$("#save-user").addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: There's no need. If you correctly disable it with jQuery UI, jQuery UI handles it: http://output.jsbin.com/momebup

Comment: Is it possible to disabled it without using jQuery UI ?

Comment: The question is about a jQuery UI button.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I know that, I just want to know that Is that possible without that ? Or we need to use CSS only or we can use unbind click event ? What you generally prefer ?

Comment: I think at this stage `pointer-events` is probably pretty well-supported. I'd still probably handle it in JS as well, but that's probably belt-and-braces.

Answer (score -1):

Easy solution: Changing your `a` tag to a `button` tag